# Fill extruded spline

Tags: extrude, splines

I would like to fill this extruded spline. In 3ds Max you extrude the splines and it automatically adds a cap. I would like to reproduce this in Blender.

[image]

[image: Extruded spline]

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: provide your blend file please

Comment: Is it still a spline right now? If so, you probably won't be able to cap it until you convert that spline to a mesh object. Blender has spline objects and curve objects, but the vast majority of its modeling tools only work with polygons. For that reason, you will often have to convert spline and curve shapes to polys before you can work with them further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the spline is extruded as you have it above, you choose (in object mode) Object>Convert to>Mesh:

[image]

Then fill in the faces (choose vertices and hit F):

[image]

[image]